# Deploy MSI silently - Cisco CAD Client Configuration

Tags: cisco, group-policy, msi, deployment, silent

Deploy a MSI using Group Policy.  Sounds easy right?

This MSI (CAD Client Configuration.msi) prompts for the IP address of our UCCX server. Most MSI's I have dealt with I can install silently uisng /q but this one not so much.

I can't assign it to the computer object becuase the prompt for the IP address is never visible.

I can't assignt it to the user object becuase they don't have the credintials to run to program.

I need to install this on 250 computers within the next 5 hours.  Any advice??

Comment: Can you provide a link to the MSI? And could you please identify which command line options you've tried to install this?

Comment: Five hours have passed.  Any luck, or follow up information, with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [SuperOrca](http://www.pantaray.com/msi_super_orca.html) and open the MSI.  Check in the `Property` table for a property which could be assigned to this IP's value.   You can then either pass the property on the command line or via a transform file (MST) to populate this property (and/or others).

Command line, assuming `IPPROP` is the IP property's name:

`msiexec /i "CAD Client Configuration.msi" IPPROP=10.0.0.1 /qn`

MST file:

`msiexec /i "CAD Client Configuration.msi" TRANSFORMS=your.transform.mst /qn`

It's also possible you may be able to simply install silently, and populate the registry with the IP value post-install.

`msiexec /i "CAD Client Configuration.msi" /qn`

Comment: I dropped the ball on this question. I ended up deploying it manually. @jscott - If I ever get time I will try your suggestion.  Thanks for you help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would run the client configuration tool first, which adds the IP address to the MSI. It is in the CAD installation guide.

*The client configuration package includes an MSI configuration tool and a stand-alone directory structure. The MSI configuration tool prompts the deployment engineer to provide the environment-specific configuration data, and then interacts with the files in the stand-alone directory to create the CAD client MSI.*